# Playing a Video and grabbing frames using a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, video-processing, windows-media-player

I am having trouble playing a video and grabbing frames. I need to grab frames to perform change detection among other things...Is there a way of playing a video and grabbing frames periodically (using a timer) such as using Windows Media Player control on a windows form?

N.B:

1. I have looked over DirectShow.NET, seems too complicated & involved for such a simple requirement. So don;t want to head that route, unless i absolutely must.
2. The AVIFile lib won't cut it since I need to support multiple video formats (other than AVI)

Comment: Found this one: http://blog.andrewnurse.net/2008/10/21/VidSpeakPart1ExtractingFramesFromVideoInC.aspx you could try with that otherwise in code project there are samples wrapping DirectShow with c# classes, your task is not trivial so don't be scared of complexity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar to this in the past with DirectShow.

You are going to get much better results with DirectShow, since you can do you calculations frame by frame rather than on a timer.

These are both examples of motion capture, that use DirectShow:
[A](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx)
[B](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/motion_detection_wc.aspx)

Comment: Great! I will look into aforge.net. Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps someone else in a similar predicament, but I used Aforge.net Motion Detection sample and built my algorithms atop it - it came with video playing, frame capturing etc. Easy peesy.